# Cycle Div ID's to make carousel (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

My website has a series of DIV's of information. Currently Im using cycle2 plugin, with all of the DIV's in a single html file. I love the effect, but I want to separate them out into different pages, for SEO and people without JS enabled. I initially tried having a central DIV, and then one spare, and when the 'next' or 'previous' buttons were pressed, I used .load to get the contents of the new DIV, then slide between them. However, this failed because the next slide needed time to load.

Now I'm trying a slightly different approach, with a left div, middle div and right div, the two side ones using .load on page load so they're ready when the link is clicked. However in order to work more than once, I need to be able to switch around the ID's of these DIVs, so if the 'next' button is pressed, the middle div goes to left, the right div to middle and the left div to right.

I know just changing them directly will inevitably mean multiple DIVs with the same ID, so I'm trying an intermediary, like this:

```
$("#divright").css('id','divleftnew');  
$("#divleft").css('id','divmiddlenew'); 
$("#divmiddle").css('id','divrightnew');    
$("#divrightnew").css('id','divright'); 
$("#divleftnew").css('id','divleft');   
$("#divmiddlenew").css('id','divmiddle');
```

However, this seems to have no effect - subsequent code affecting a DIV will affect the originally named one, not the new one.

If anyone has any ideas how to cycle the ID's, or a better solution, I'd be very grateful :)

Comment: The ID isn't a CSS property.

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.css()`

Comment: Thanks, sorry silly mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use attr.

```
$("#divmiddlenew").attr('id','divmiddle');
```